# Using Guard to replicate Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline, guard

I am attempting to replicate the Rails asset-pipeline for a non-Rails project I am working on . I have the necessary plugins installed for coffeescript, haml-coffee and sass, and I was wondering if there is anyway I can get Guard to read, or if there's anything else I can do, to read from an application.js.coffee manifest file like in the Rails asset pipeline (where I can require all of my libraries and dependencies).

Finally - what plugin would I need/use to combine, compile, and minify all of my JS and CSS files upon deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually solved this myself by discovering the `guard sprockets` plugin.

It emulates the assets-pipeline by allowing you to use js, coffeescript, css and sass manifest files.

https://github.com/pferdefleisch/guard-sprockets